# Nautilus not launching

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, filemanager

I've been having some problems for the last few days with Nautilus file manager. It suddenly stopped launching. I tried to remove it and install Nemo, but it made it worse. However I fixed that and I'm back at the same state.

After trying some stuff I found online (killall nautilus, reinstalling, updating, etc) I updated my system from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 to see if something happenned. It's slightly better now because when I launch it from the terminal I see the icon popping for a sec, but then it dissappears and reports a bus error.

When I run it as superuser I get this:

```
    Nautilus-Share-Message: 00:25:34.658: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 
Falló al ejecutar el proceso hijo «net» (No such file or directory)
```

I also tried modifying the default applications file (as someone reported as their solution online) and this is it right now:

```
[MIME Cache]
application/bzip2=org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
application/clarisworks=libreoffice-writer.desktop;libreoffice-calc.desktop;libreoffice-draw.desktop;
application/csv=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/excel=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/gzip=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
application/illustrator=evince.desktop;
application/ipfix=wireshark.desktop;
application/java-archive=JB-java-jdk8.desktop;
application/macwriteii=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/mathml+xml=libreoffice-math.desktop;
application/msexcel=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/mspowerpoint=libreoffice-impress.desktop;
application/msword=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/mxf=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
application/ogg=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;rhythmbox.desktop;
application/oxps=evince.desktop;
application/pdf=evince.desktop;libreoffice-draw.desktop;
application/pkcs10=gcr-viewer.desktop;
application/pkcs10+pem=gcr-viewer.desktop;
application/pkcs12=gcr-viewer.desktop;
application/pkcs12+pem=gcr-viewer.desktop;
application/pkcs7-mime=gcr-viewer.desktop;
application/pkcs7-mime+pem=gcr-viewer.desktop;
application/pkcs8=gcr-viewer.desktop;
application/pkcs8+pem=gcr-viewer.desktop;
application/pkix-cert=gcr-viewer.desktop;
application/pkix-cert+pem=gcr-viewer.desktop;
application/pkix-crl=gcr-viewer.desktop;
application/pkix-crl+pem=gcr-viewer.desktop;
application/postscript=evince.desktop;
application/prs.plucker=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/ram=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
application/rdf+xml=firefox.desktop;
application/rss+xml=firefox.desktop;
application/rtf=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/sdp=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
application/smil=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
application/smil+xml=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
application/tab-separated-values=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.apple.mpegurl=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
application/vnd.comicbook+zip=evince.desktop;
application/vnd.comicbook-rar=evince.desktop;
application/vnd.corel-draw=libreoffice-draw.desktop;
application/vnd.debian.binary-package=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/vnd.flatpak=gnome-software-local-file.desktop;
application/vnd.flatpak.ref=gnome-software-local-file.desktop;
application/vnd.flatpak.repo=gnome-software-local-file.desktop;
application/vnd.lotus-1-2-3=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.lotus-wordpro=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.ms-asf=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;gnome-software-local-file.desktop;
application/vnd.ms-excel=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.ms-excel.template.macroEnabled.12=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint=libreoffice-impress.desktop;
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.presentation.macroEnabled.12=libreoffice-impress.desktop;
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.slideshow.macroEnabled.12=libreoffice-impress.desktop;
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint.template.macroEnabled.12=libreoffice-impress.desktop;
application/vnd.ms-publisher=libreoffice-draw.desktop;
application/vnd.ms-word=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.ms-works=libreoffice-writer.desktop;libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.ms-wpl=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument=evince.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart-template=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula=libreoffice-math.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula-template=libreoffice-math.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics=libreoffice-draw.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-flat-xml=libreoffice-xsltfilter.desktop;libreoffice-draw.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics-template=libreoffice-draw.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation=libreoffice-impress.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-flat-xml=libreoffice-impress.desktop;libreoffice-xsltfilter.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation-template=libreoffice-impress.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-flat-xml=libreoffice-xsltfilter.desktop;libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet-template=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-flat-xml=libreoffice-writer.desktop;libreoffice-xsltfilter.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master-template=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-template=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.openofficeorg.extension=libreoffice-startcenter.desktop;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation=libreoffice-impress.desktop;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide=libreoffice-impress.desktop;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow=libreoffice-impress.desktop;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template=libreoffice-impress.desktop;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.palm=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.rn-realmedia=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
application/vnd.rn-realmedia-vbr=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
application/vnd.snap=gnome-software-local-file.desktop;
application/vnd.stardivision.writer-global=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.sun.xml.calc=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.sun.xml.calc.template=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.sun.xml.draw=libreoffice-draw.desktop;
application/vnd.sun.xml.draw.template=libreoffice-draw.desktop;
application/vnd.sun.xml.impress=libreoffice-impress.desktop;
application/vnd.sun.xml.impress.template=libreoffice-impress.desktop;
application/vnd.sun.xml.math=libreoffice-math.desktop;
application/vnd.sun.xml.writer=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.global=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.template=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.tcpdump.pcap=wireshark.desktop;wireshark-gtk.desktop;
application/vnd.visio=libreoffice-draw.desktop;
application/vnd.wordperfect=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/wordperfect=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/x-123=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/x-5view=wireshark.desktop;wireshark-gtk.desktop;
application/x-7z-compressed=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
application/x-7z-compressed-tar=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
application/x-abiword=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/x-ace=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-alz=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-aportisdoc=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/x-app-package=gnome-software-local-file.desktop;
application/x-apple-packetlogger=wireshark.desktop;
application/x-ar=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-archive=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-arj=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-bittorrent=transmission-gtk.desktop;
application/x-bzdvi=evince.desktop;
application/x-bzip=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
application/x-bzip-compressed-tar=mount-archive.desktop;org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
application/x-bzip1=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-bzip1-compressed-tar=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-bzpdf=evince.desktop;
application/x-bzpostscript=evince.desktop;
application/x-cabinet=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-cb7=evince.desktop;
application/x-cbr=evince.desktop;
application/x-cbt=evince.desktop;
application/x-cbz=evince.desktop;
application/x-cd-image=mount-archive.desktop;org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;gnome-disk-image-mounter.desktop;gnome-disk-image-writer.desktop;
application/x-compress=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
application/x-compressed-tar=mount-archive.desktop;org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
application/x-cpio=mount-archive.desktop;org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
application/x-dbase=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/x-dbf=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/x-deb=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;gnome-software-local-file.desktop;
application/x-doc=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/x-dos_ms_excel=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/x-dvi=evince.desktop;
application/x-ear=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-endace-erf=wireshark.desktop;
application/x-etherpeek=wireshark.desktop;wireshark-gtk.desktop;
application/x-excel=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/x-ext-cb7=evince.desktop;
application/x-ext-cbr=evince.desktop;
application/x-ext-cbt=evince.desktop;
application/x-ext-cbz=evince.desktop;
application/x-ext-djv=evince.desktop;
application/x-ext-djvu=evince.desktop;
application/x-ext-dvi=evince.desktop;
application/x-ext-eps=evince.desktop;
application/x-ext-pdf=evince.desktop;
application/x-ext-ps=evince.desktop;
application/x-extension-m4a=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
application/x-extension-mp4=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
application/x-extension-txt=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/x-fictionbook+xml=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/x-flac=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
application/x-flash-video=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
application/x-font-otf=org.gnome.font-viewer.desktop;
application/x-font-pcf=org.gnome.font-viewer.desktop;
application/x-font-ttf=org.gnome.font-viewer.desktop;
application/x-font-type1=org.gnome.font-viewer.desktop;
application/x-gnome-saved-search=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop;
application/x-gtar=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-gzdvi=evince.desktop;
application/x-gzip=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
application/x-gzpdf=evince.desktop;
application/x-gzpostscript=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;evince.desktop;
application/x-hwp=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/x-iptrace=wireshark.desktop;wireshark-gtk.desktop;
application/x-iwork-keynote-sffkey=libreoffice-impress.desktop;
application/x-iwork-numbers-sffnumbers=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/x-iwork-pages-sffpages=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/x-ixia-vwr=wireshark.desktop;
application/x-jar=JB-java-jdk8.desktop;
application/x-java-archive=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;JB-java-jdk8.desktop;
application/x-java-jnlp-file=JB-javaws-jdk8.desktop;
application/x-lanalyzer=wireshark.desktop;wireshark-gtk.desktop;
application/x-lha=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
application/x-lhz=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-lrzip=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-lrzip-compressed-tar=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-lz4=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-lz4-compressed-tar=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-lzip=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
application/x-lzip-compressed-tar=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
application/x-lzma=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
application/x-lzma-compressed-tar=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
application/x-lzop=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-lzop-compressed-tar=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-matroska=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
application/x-micropross-mplog=wireshark.desktop;
application/x-ms-dos-executable=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-ms-excel=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/x-ms-wim=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-msexcel=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/x-mswrite=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/x-netinstobserver=wireshark.desktop;wireshark-gtk.desktop;
application/x-netshow-channel=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
application/x-nettl=wireshark.desktop;wireshark-gtk.desktop;
application/x-ogg=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;rhythmbox.desktop;
application/x-pagemaker=libreoffice-draw.desktop;
application/x-pcapng=wireshark.desktop;wireshark-gtk.desktop;
application/x-pem-file=gcr-viewer.desktop;
application/x-pem-key=gcr-viewer.desktop;
application/x-pkcs12=gcr-viewer.desktop;
application/x-pkcs7-certificates=gcr-viewer.desktop;
application/x-quattropro=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/x-quicktime-media-link=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
application/x-quicktimeplayer=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
application/x-radcom=wireshark.desktop;wireshark-gtk.desktop;
application/x-rar=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-rar-compressed=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-raw-disk-image=gnome-disk-image-mounter.desktop;gnome-disk-image-writer.desktop;
application/x-raw-disk-image-xz-compressed=gnome-disk-image-writer.desktop;
application/x-redhat-package-manager=gnome-software-local-file.desktop;
application/x-remmina=remmina-file.desktop;
application/x-rpm=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;gnome-software-local-file.desktop;
application/x-rzip=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-rzip-compressed-tar=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-shellscript=vim.desktop;
application/x-shorten=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
application/x-smil=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
application/x-snoop=wireshark.desktop;wireshark-gtk.desktop;
application/x-sony-bbeb=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/x-source-rpm=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-spkac=gcr-viewer.desktop;
application/x-spkac+base64=gcr-viewer.desktop;
application/x-starcalc=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/x-stardraw=libreoffice-draw.desktop;
application/x-starwriter=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/x-stuffit=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-t602=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/x-tar=mount-archive.desktop;org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
application/x-tarz=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
application/x-tektronix-rf5=wireshark.desktop;wireshark-gtk.desktop;
application/x-visualnetworks=wireshark.desktop;wireshark-gtk.desktop;
application/x-war=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-wpg=libreoffice-draw.desktop;
application/x-x509-ca-cert=gcr-viewer.desktop;
application/x-x509-user-cert=gcr-viewer.desktop;
application/x-xar=org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
application/x-xpinstall=thunderbird.desktop;firefox.desktop;
application/x-xz=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
application/x-xz-compressed-tar=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
application/x-xzpdf=evince.desktop;
application/x-zip=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-zip-compressed=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/x-zoo=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
application/xhtml+xml=firefox.desktop;
application/xml=firefox.desktop;
application/xspf+xml=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
application/zip=mount-archive.desktop;org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop;
audio/3gpp=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/3gpp2=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/AMR=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/AMR-WB=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/aac=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/ac3=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/basic=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/dv=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/eac3=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/flac=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/m4a=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/midi=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/mp1=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/mp2=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/mp3=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/mp4=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;rhythmbox.desktop;
audio/mpeg=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;rhythmbox.desktop;
audio/mpegurl=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/mpg=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/ogg=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/opus=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/prs.sid=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/scpls=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/vnd.rn-realaudio=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/vorbis=rhythmbox.desktop;
audio/wav=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/webm=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-aac=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-aiff=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-ape=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-flac=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;rhythmbox.desktop;
audio/x-gsm=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-it=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;rhythmbox.desktop;
audio/x-m4a=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-matroska=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-mod=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;rhythmbox.desktop;
audio/x-mp1=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-mp2=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-mp3=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;rhythmbox.desktop;
audio/x-mpeg=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;rhythmbox.desktop;
audio/x-mpegurl=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;rhythmbox.desktop;
audio/x-mpg=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-ms-asf=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-ms-asx=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-ms-wax=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-ms-wma=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-musepack=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-pn-aiff=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-pn-au=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-pn-realaudio=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-pn-wav=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-pn-windows-acm=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-real-audio=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-realaudio=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-s3m=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;rhythmbox.desktop;
audio/x-sbc=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-scpls=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;rhythmbox.desktop;
audio/x-shorten=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-speex=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-stm=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;rhythmbox.desktop;
audio/x-tta=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-vorbis=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;rhythmbox.desktop;
audio/x-vorbis+ogg=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;rhythmbox.desktop;
audio/x-wav=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-wavpack=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
audio/x-xm=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;rhythmbox.desktop;
font/otf=org.gnome.font-viewer.desktop;
font/ttf=org.gnome.font-viewer.desktop;
image/bmp=eog.desktop;
image/gif=firefox.desktop;eog.desktop;
image/jpeg=firefox.desktop;shotwell-viewer.desktop;eog.desktop;
image/jpg=shotwell-viewer.desktop;eog.desktop;
image/pjpeg=shotwell-viewer.desktop;eog.desktop;
image/png=firefox.desktop;shotwell-viewer.desktop;eog.desktop;
image/svg+xml=eog.desktop;
image/svg+xml-compressed=eog.desktop;
image/tiff=shotwell-viewer.desktop;evince.desktop;eog.desktop;
image/vnd.djvu+multipage=evince.desktop;
image/vnd.rn-realpix=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
image/vnd.wap.wbmp=eog.desktop;
image/x-3fr=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-adobe-dng=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-arw=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-bay=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-bmp=shotwell-viewer.desktop;eog.desktop;
image/x-bzeps=evince.desktop;
image/x-canon-cr2=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-canon-crw=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-cap=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-cr2=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-crw=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-dcr=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-dcraw=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-dcs=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-dng=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-drf=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-eip=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-eps=evince.desktop;
image/x-erf=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-fff=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-freehand=libreoffice-draw.desktop;
image/x-fuji-raf=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-gray=eog.desktop;
image/x-gzeps=evince.desktop;
image/x-icb=eog.desktop;
image/x-ico=eog.desktop;
image/x-iiq=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-k25=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-kdc=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-mef=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-minolta-mrw=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-mos=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-mrw=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-nef=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-nikon-nef=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-nrw=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-olympus-orf=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-orf=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-panasonic-raw=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-pcx=eog.desktop;
image/x-pef=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-pentax-pef=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-pict=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
image/x-png=shotwell-viewer.desktop;eog.desktop;
image/x-portable-anymap=eog.desktop;
image/x-portable-bitmap=eog.desktop;
image/x-portable-graymap=eog.desktop;
image/x-portable-pixmap=eog.desktop;
image/x-ptx=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-pxn=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-r3d=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-raf=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-raw=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-rw2=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-rwl=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-rwz=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-sigma-x3f=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-sony-arw=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-sony-sr2=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-sony-srf=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-sr2=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-srf=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-x3f=shotwell-viewer.desktop;
image/x-xbitmap=eog.desktop;
image/x-xpixmap=eog.desktop;
inode/directory=org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop
misc/ultravox=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
text/calendar=org.gnome.Calendar.desktop;
text/comma-separated-values=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
text/csv=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
text/english=vim.desktop;
text/google-video-pointer=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
text/html=firefox.desktop;
text/mathml=libreoffice-math.desktop;
text/plain=libreoffice-writer.desktop;org.gnome.gedit.desktop;vim.desktop;
text/rtf=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
text/spreadsheet=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
text/tab-separated-values=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
text/x-apport=apport-gtk.desktop;
text/x-apt-sources-list=software-properties-gtk.desktop;
text/x-c=vim.desktop;
text/x-c++=vim.desktop;
text/x-c++hdr=vim.desktop;
text/x-c++src=vim.desktop;
text/x-chdr=vim.desktop;
text/x-comma-separated-values=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
text/x-csrc=vim.desktop;
text/x-csv=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
text/x-google-video-pointer=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
text/x-java=vim.desktop;
text/x-makefile=vim.desktop;
text/x-moc=vim.desktop;
text/x-pascal=vim.desktop;
text/x-tcl=vim.desktop;
text/x-tex=vim.desktop;
text/xml=firefox.desktop;
video/3gp=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/3gpp=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/3gpp2=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/divx=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/dv=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/fli=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/flv=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/mp2t=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/mp4=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/mp4v-es=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/mpeg=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/mpeg-system=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/msvideo=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/ogg=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/quicktime=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/vivo=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/vnd.divx=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/vnd.mpegurl=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/vnd.rn-realvideo=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/vnd.vivo=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/webm=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;firefox.desktop;
video/x-anim=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-avi=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-flc=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-fli=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-flic=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-flv=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-m4v=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-matroska=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-mpeg=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-mpeg2=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-ms-asf=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-ms-asf-plugin=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-ms-asx=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-ms-wm=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-ms-wmv=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-ms-wmx=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-ms-wvx=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-msvideo=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-nsv=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-ogm+ogg=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-theora=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-theora+ogg=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
video/x-totem-stream=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
x-content/audio-cdda=rhythmbox-device.desktop;
x-content/audio-player=rhythmbox-device.desktop;
x-content/image-dcf=shotwell.desktop;
x-content/unix-software=nautilus-autorun-software.desktop;
x-content/video-dvd=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
x-content/video-svcd=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
x-content/video-vcd=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/appstream=org.gnome.Software.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/apt=org.gnome.Software.desktop;apturl.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/chrome=firefox.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/ftp=firefox.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/ghelp=yelp.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/help=yelp.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/http=firefox.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/https=firefox.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/icy=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/icyx=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/info=yelp.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/magnet=transmission-gtk.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/mailto=thunderbird.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/man=yelp.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/mms=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/mmsh=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/net=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/pnm=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/rtmp=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/rtp=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/rtsp=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/skype=skypeforlinux.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/snap=org.gnome.Software.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/spotify=spotify.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/uvox=org.gnome.Totem.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/vnd.libreoffice.cmis=libreoffice-startcenter.desktop;
```

There were some other values to inode/directory before. But changing it as suggested [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=157033) didn't change anything.
If I do nautilus --check it gets stuck at running nautilus_self_check_directory.
If I try restarting it (nautilus -q), it doesn't show anything.
I guess it's something more serious than it seems. Probably something wrong in my system.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with samba, judging by the "net usershare info" message. Is samba-common-bin installed?

Comment: no it isn't. Should I install it? I have a Windows partition that I've been accessing from Ubuntu lately. Could it be something related to that? @TSJNachos117

Comment: What is tho output of the following: `dpkg-query --showformat '${package}\n' -W 'nautilus*'`?

Comment: Also, your Windows partition is probably irrelevant.

Comment: This is what I get: `nautilus
nautilus-data
nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal
nautilus-sendto
nautilus-share`@TSJNachos117

Comment: OK, I think I know what is causing your problem. See below for my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems are being caused by a Nautilus plugin that in turn makes it easier to share files via Server Message Blocks, also known as SMB. To use SMB, you need Samba, which you don't seem to have.

Ultimately, you have two options:

1. Install Samba. This will give you the ability to use SMB. One major advantage of this is the ease of sharing files with Windows machines, as those machines won't need to install extra software. (On the Windows machine, simply type `//host/` in the address bar on Explorer, replacing "host" with the host name of the machine.) Keep in mind that SMB doesn't use encryption, which makes it a security risk over WiFi networks. To install Samba, simply run (as root) `apt install samba`.
2. Remove the nautilus-share package. If you don't intend to share files in this way, this is probably the best solution you can ask for. To remove this package, run (as root) `apt purge nautilus-share`.

Good luck.